# Maximum debug info from Steel Bank Common Lisp & Slime

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, slime, sbcl

What's the best way to initialise a Lisp session (I'm using Slime and sbcl) such that functions are always compiled with the maximum amount of debug information?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`(sb-ext:restrict-compiler-policy 'debug 3)` in the repl or your .sbclrc will do it.

Comment: `(sb-ext:describe-compiler-policy)`

Comment: Thanks. I tried to find this out for myself - is there a reference I should have checked? I couldn't see anything in or around here http://sbcl.sourceforge.net/manual/Debugger-Policy-Control.html

Comment: Just part of the lore. The source of the function says it's experimental, so maybe that's why it's not part of the manual yet.